# Automate Builds in .net

Tags: .net, build, automation, vdproj

I have a solution sln, with 50 projects (vbproj, csproj, and setup project).

I need automatize Build of all solution, and projects (set of projects of solution folder), and setup project (vdproj).

My vdproj (setup project) has Post Build Event..

First, how can I automatize build for vdproj ?? I only can execute a command for build it in release and the copy Outputs (setup.exe, *.msi) to another folder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are number of application which can help you to make automatic build, e.g. [Cruise Control](http://cruisecontrol.sourceforge.net/).

Additionally, you can create your own by using the [MSBUILD.EXE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164311.aspx), that is part of Windows SDK.

Comment: +1 to Cruise Control.  I can't speak to other CI servers, because I haven't used them, but Cruise Control is very easy to use and it is reliable and free.

Comment: @Bhaskar: MSBUILD.EXE is part of the Windows SDK, not part of Visual Studio.

Answer (score 4):

Are you using Visual Studio? If so, you can call the IDE "devenv.exe" with command line parameters in a batch file, for example

```
devenv.exe YourSolution.sln /build "Release" /out Build.log
```

(devenv.exe is located in the folder Common7\IDE\ of your VS installation).

Answer (score 1):

Use TeamCity it is a best tool on the market and have a free Professional License.
From creators of ReSharper - http://www.jetbrains.com .

We use TeamCity about 2 years without any problems for really BIG projects.

As for vdproj you can build it via msbuild just google that, we for example use WiX for such a thing.

Answer (score 1):

If you have extra cash to spare, you can try [Final Builder](http://www.finalbuilder.com/) or [Automated Build Studio](http://www.automatedqa.com/products/abs/). Both are GUI based build tools, which means you don't have to write a lot of scripts for mundane tasks.

Answer (score 1):

> Hi all,
>
> is the same use devenv than msbuild ??
>
> 1.)
>
> devenv.exe YourSolution.sln /build
>   "Release" /out Build.log
>   2.)
>
> @echo off  SET
>   EXEC="C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\MSBuild.exe"
>   %EXEC% ....\ExpedienteElectronico.sln
>   /t:Rebuild /p:Configuration=Release
>   pause

It is not the same. devenv is able to process vdproj files where as msbuild cannot deal with this project type.